# MVC4 how to use a global queue-collection variable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, queue

I have done some investigation but I still can't work out how to use a global collection variable within different controllers. In `global.asax`, I've placed a queue collection (first in first out), but can't find a way to address this from within a controller.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static Queue<SMS_PR> Production_FIFO;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        Production_FIFO = new Queue<SMS_PR>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: one controllers must add some sms messages to the queue and another controller reads the queue over and over after a delaytime...

Comment: It would be an absolutely terrible idea to use a non thread safe collection such as `Queue<T>` in a multithreaded environment such as an ASP.NET MVC application. Have you thought what would happen to this collection if 2 concurrent users attempt to access it at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You could access this variable from your controllers like that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MvcApplication.Production_FIFO ...
}
```

This being said, the [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is not thread safe, so attempting to do that in a multithreaded environment such as an ASP.NET MVC application would probably result in an exception if multiple users access this collection at the same time.

You might consider using a [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static ConcurrentQueue<SMS_PR> Production_FIFO;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        Production_FIFO = new ConcurrentQueue<SMS_PR>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class variable in `MvcApplication` is not easily available in your controllers.

If you add the shared resource to the `Application` collection, you would get the same instance from all controllers. In `Application_Start`:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        Production_FIFO = new Queue<SMS_PR>();
        Application["SharedQueue"] = Production_FIFO;
    }
}
```

Then, from your controllers:

```
public class MyController : System.Web.Controller
{
    protected ActionResult UseQueue()
    {
       var queue = Application["SharedQueue"];
       // use queue
    }
}
```

Or, you could use a container to hold the queue (e.g. Unity or some other IoC container)

Comment: Thanks Erik. Darin, you're remark probably is correct concerning a web application, but this project is a stand alone app without web access.

Comment: Just to make it clear, your `MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication` is not an MVC application?

Comment: Erik, it is indeed an MVC application, but not used as a website. the data comes from an sql database.

Comment: OK, so why is that relevant? Because of the concurrency issue, then?